# MySQL: Get thread starter and latest poster in one query

Tags: mysql, forum

I've been having some troubles getting both the thread starter and the latest poster in one query. My tables look like this:

forum_categories
id
name
description

forum_threads
id
title
category_id

forum_posts
id
thread_id
user_id
message
created
edited

I use the following query to get all the details I need, except for the user_id of the person who posted the last post in a specific thread.

```
SELECT T.id, T.title, MAX(P.created) AS lastPostDate, COUNT(P.id) AS amountOfPosts, M.MemberID, M.Username
FROM forum_threads T 
JOIN forum_posts P 
ON T.id = P.thread_id 
JOIN member M 
ON P.user_id = M.MemberID 
WHERE category_id = 1
GROUP BY T.id 
ORDER BY lastPostDate DESC
```

A sample result I get is:

```
id: 19
title: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP
lastPostDate: 2014-04-25 13:42:53
amountOfPosts: 25
MemberID: 1
Username: monkeyboy
```

I am able to get the details of the last poster as well and am able to get it alongside the details from the above query using union, but I have a feeling there must be a better way to do so. So can anyway help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: your query looks nice and simple , how you mean you want do it ?

Comment: What I currently get is the userid/name of the user who added the thread (first post of a certain threadid). Besides this person's id/name, I would also like to get the id/name of the last person to reply in the thread.

Comment: This is something of a FAQ.

Comment: I haven't been able to find an answer though. Could you at least provide me with a link then?